What writing system are they using in "Knight's & Magic"?
What language or writing system are the characters using in the anime, "Knight's & Magic"?
For Example:



Is it just a made up language and writing system or is it based off of any existing language and writing system?
Also, what's with the Sacred Geometry?

There are two writing systems shown in the first picture.
One of them is comprised of various characters, for example:
Greek Letters:              ΒΙΔΨΧΖΘ
Latin Letters:              KLVDRWUgS
Variation on Latin Letters: Ħ

The other also appears in the other images. I am suspecting it to be a fancy font to write either Hiragana or Katakana.

The first one seems to be either pure nonsense or is encoded in such a way that I cannot decode it based on the information I have.
The second one eludes me due to my insufficient Japanese knowledge. But given the way the patterns repeat, sometimes with omitted letters and that one word is rotated 180° I am inclined to say that it doesn't convey useful information.
